# How to close .NET MAUI App on iOS from code behind?

Tags: maui

I want to close MAUI app from code behind

I'm using `Application.Current.Quit()`

on Android it works

but on iOS it doesn't work

Does everyone know is there any way to close MAUI app on iOS

Many thanks

Comment: IOS specifically prohibits doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
System.Environment.Exit(0);
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Only use for development / testing purposes, Apple will refuse your app on the store if you try to use it anyway. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html

Comment: To be honest, I haven't tested submitting to  App Store. Have you tried that?

Comment: I didn't dare to try to submit one with this line :D

Comment: So that's worth a try, if there is a chance :D